# ¿COMO LO SOLUCIONO? Me sale un error en line 110, in <module> Lista_Actividad(4) NameError: name 'Lista_Actividad' is not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

```
# importando modulos necesarios


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

import seaborn as sns
import random as rm

#Estados(Nodos)-->4 EVENTOS
Estados=["Dormir","Entrenar","Correr","Jugar"]
Lista_Actividad=[]
#Posibles secuencias de eventos.
NombreTransicion=[["DD","DE","DC","DJ"],["ED","EE","EC","EJ"],["CD","CE","CC","CJ"],["JD","JE","JC","JJ"]]

#Matriz de probabilidades(Matriz de transicion).
MatrizTransicion=[[0.1,0.4,0.3,0.2],[0.3,0.1,0.3,0.3],[0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3],[0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2]]
#Verificamos si la matriz esta correcta;debe sumar +1 cada matriz de transicion y dar como resultado 4.
if sum(MatrizTransicion[0])+sum(MatrizTransicion[1])+sum(MatrizTransicion[2])+sum(MatrizTransicion[3])!=4:
     print("En alguna parte de la MatrizTransicion,hay un error;Verifique..")
else: print("¡¡¡No hay ningun Error!!!")
#Funcion que implementa la Cadena de Markov para pronosticar estados.
#1-Se Elije el estado inicial.
#2-Se Guarda el estado en una secuancia de array.
#3-Se calcula la probabilidad de Lista_Actividad
def PronosticarActividad(dias):
    Actividad_Hoy="Dormir"
    print("Empezar Estado: "+Actividad_Hoy)
    Lista_Actividad=[Actividad_Hoy]
    i=0
    prob=1
    while i!=dias:
        if Actividad_Hoy=="Dormir":
            cambio= np.random.choice(NombreTransicion[0],reemplazar=True,p=MatrizTransicion[0])
            if cambio=="DD":
                prob= prob * 0.1
                Lista_Actividad.append("Dormir")
                pass
            elif cambio=="DE":
                prob=prob*0.4
                Actividad_Hoy="Entrenar"
                Lista_Actividad.append("Entrenar")
            elif cambio=="DC":
                prob=prob*0.3
                Actividad_Hoy="Correr"
                Lista_Actividad.append("Correr")
            else:
                prob=prob*0.2
                Actividad_Hoy="Jugar"
                Lista_Actividad.append("Jugar")
        elif Actividad_Hoy=="Entrenar":
            cambio=np.random.choice(NombreTransicion[1],reemplazar=True,p=MatrizTransicion[1])
            if cambio=="EE":
                 prob=prob*0.1
                 Lista_Actividad.append("Entrenar")
                 pass
            elif cambio=="ED":
                 prob=prob*0.3
                 Actividad_Hoy="Dormir"
                 Lista_Actividad.append("Dormir")
            elif cambio=="EC":
                 prob=prob*0.3
                 Actividad_Hoy="Correr"
                 Lista_Actividad.append("Correr")
            else:
                 prob=prob*0.3
                 Actividad_Hoy="Jugar"
                 Lista_Actividad.append("Jugar")
        elif Actividad_Hoy=="Correr":
             cambio=np.random.choice(NombreTransicion[2],reemplazar=True,p=MatrizTransicion[2])
             if cambio=="CC":
                  pro=prob*0.3
                  Lista_Actividad.append("Correr")
                  pass
             elif cambio=="CD":
                  prob=prob*0.2
                  Actividad_Hoy="Dormir"
                  Lista_Actividad.append("Dormir")
             elif cambio=="CE":
                  prob=prob*0.2
                  Actividad_Hoy="Entrenar"
                  Lista_Actividad.append("Entrenar")
             else:
                  prob=prob*0.3
                  Actividad_Hoy="Jugar"
                  Lista_Actividad.append("Jugar")
        elif Actividad_Hoy=="Jugar":
             cambio=np.random.choice(NombreTransicion[3],reemplazar=True,p=MatrizTransicion[3])
             if cambio=="JJ":
                  prob=prob*0.2
                  Lista_Actividad.append("Jugar")
                  pass
             elif cambio=="JD":
                  prob=prob*0.3
                  Actividad_Hoy="Dormir"
                  Lista_Actividad.append("Dormir")
             elif cambio=="JE":
                  prob=prob*0.1
                  Actividad_Hoy="Entrenar"
                  Lista_Actividad.append("Entrenar")
             else:
                  prob=prob*0.4
                  Actividad_Hoy="Correr"
                  Lista_Actividad.append("Correr")
        i+=1
     #return Lista_Actividad
    print("Possible states: " + Lista_Actividad)
    print("End state after "+ (dias) + " days: " + Actividad_Hoy)
    print("Probability of the possible sequence of states: " + prob )
Lista_Actividad(4)



# Guardar toda la lista
#Lista_Actividad = []
#count = 0

#for iterations in range(1,10000):
#     Lista_Actividad.append(PronosticarActividad(2))

#for Lista_P in Lista_Actividad:
#     if(Lista_P[3] == "Jugar"):
#        count += 1

#porc = (count/10000) * 100
#print("La probabilidad de empezar el estado Dormir:'Dormir' y finalizando estado:'Jugar'= " + str(porc) + "%")
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer como crear un [mcve].

Comment: Para que respondes si no me vas a ayudar??soy novato,por eso pregunto..

Comment: No respondí. Escribí un comentario. Te invito también a hacer el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio.

Answer (score 1):

En referencia al error que te surge, es porque estas llamando a la lista como si fuera una función, supongo que lo que querías hacer era llamar a `PronosticoActividad(dias)` por lo tanto con cambiar el nombre de la llamada, ya lo tendrías solucionado, aunque por lo que veo tienes un par de errores mas, los cuales me he tomado la libertad de corregir:

- Cuando llamas al método `random.choice` cuando pasas los parametros opcionales, debes nombrar ese parametro correctamente, que en este caso seria `replace` y no reemplazar.
- También debes tener en cuenta que cuando concatenas strings con integers, floats, etc., debes hacer una conversión a string sino tambien te provocará una excepción.

Aquí tienes el código rectificado:

```
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# import seaborn as sns
# import random as rm

#Estados(Nodos)-->4 EVENTOS
Estados=["Dormir","Entrenar","Correr","Jugar"]
Lista_Actividad=[]
#Posibles secuencias de eventos.
NombreTransicion=[["DD","DE","DC","DJ"],["ED","EE","EC","EJ"],["CD","CE","CC","CJ"],["JD","JE","JC","JJ"]]

#Matriz de probabilidades(Matriz de transicion).
MatrizTransicion=[[0.1,0.4,0.3,0.2],[0.3,0.1,0.3,0.3],[0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3],[0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2]]
#Verificamos si la matriz esta correcta;debe sumar +1 cada matriz de transicion y dar como resultado 4.
if sum(MatrizTransicion[0])+sum(MatrizTransicion[1])+sum(MatrizTransicion[2])+sum(MatrizTransicion[3])!=4:
     print("En alguna parte de la MatrizTransicion,hay un error;Verifique..")
else: print("¡¡¡No hay ningun Error!!!")
#Funcion que implementa la Cadena de Markov para pronosticar estados.
#1-Se Elije el estado inicial.
#2-Se Guarda el estado en una secuancia de array.
#3-Se calcula la probabilidad de Lista_Actividad
def PronosticarActividad(dias):
    Actividad_Hoy="Dormir"
    print("Empezar Estado: "+Actividad_Hoy)
    Lista_Actividad=[Actividad_Hoy]
    i=0
    prob=1
    while i!=dias:
        if Actividad_Hoy=="Dormir":
            cambio= np.random.choice(NombreTransicion[0],replace=True,p=MatrizTransicion[0])
            if cambio=="DD":
                prob= prob * 0.1
                Lista_Actividad.append("Dormir")
                pass
            elif cambio=="DE":
                prob=prob*0.4
                Actividad_Hoy="Entrenar"
                Lista_Actividad.append("Entrenar")
            elif cambio=="DC":
                prob=prob*0.3
                Actividad_Hoy="Correr"
                Lista_Actividad.append("Correr")
            else:
                prob=prob*0.2
                Actividad_Hoy="Jugar"
                Lista_Actividad.append("Jugar")
        elif Actividad_Hoy=="Entrenar":
            cambio=np.random.choice(NombreTransicion[1],replace=True,p=MatrizTransicion[1])
            if cambio=="EE":
                 prob=prob*0.1
                 Lista_Actividad.append("Entrenar")
                 pass
            elif cambio=="ED":
                 prob=prob*0.3
                 Actividad_Hoy="Dormir"
                 Lista_Actividad.append("Dormir")
            elif cambio=="EC":
                 prob=prob*0.3
                 Actividad_Hoy="Correr"
                 Lista_Actividad.append("Correr")
            else:
                 prob=prob*0.3
                 Actividad_Hoy="Jugar"
                 Lista_Actividad.append("Jugar")
        elif Actividad_Hoy=="Correr":
             cambio=np.random.choice(NombreTransicion[2],replace=True,p=MatrizTransicion[2])
             if cambio=="CC":
                  pro=prob*0.3
                  Lista_Actividad.append("Correr")
                  pass
             elif cambio=="CD":
                  prob=prob*0.2
                  Actividad_Hoy="Dormir"
                  Lista_Actividad.append("Dormir")
             elif cambio=="CE":
                  prob=prob*0.2
                  Actividad_Hoy="Entrenar"
                  Lista_Actividad.append("Entrenar")
             else:
                  prob=prob*0.3
                  Actividad_Hoy="Jugar"
                  Lista_Actividad.append("Jugar")
        elif Actividad_Hoy=="Jugar":
             cambio=np.random.choice(NombreTransicion[3],replace=True,p=MatrizTransicion[3])
             if cambio=="JJ":
                  prob=prob*0.2
                  Lista_Actividad.append("Jugar")
                  pass
             elif cambio=="JD":
                  prob=prob*0.3
                  Actividad_Hoy="Dormir"
                  Lista_Actividad.append("Dormir")
             elif cambio=="JE":
                  prob=prob*0.1
                  Actividad_Hoy="Entrenar"
                  Lista_Actividad.append("Entrenar")
             else:
                  prob=prob*0.4
                  Actividad_Hoy="Correr"
                  Lista_Actividad.append("Correr")
        i+=1
     #return Lista_Actividad
    print("Possible states: " + str(Lista_Actividad))
    print("End state after "+ str(dias) + " days: " + Actividad_Hoy)
    print("Probability of the possible sequence of states: " + str(prob) )
PronosticarActividad(4)
```